# Easiest way to simulate Cordova plugins?

Tags: android, cordova, intel-xdk

I'm a relative PHP newbie (10 months) and Javascript absolute novice, so please go easy on me.

I've just started playing with Cordova and have a couple of small apps for use internally within our small business that I could really do with, but testing my code is causing me grief.  I've been using Intel XDK with the built in simulator, but it can't simulate SQLite or the FileTransfer plugin.

At the moment, the only way I can see of doing this in XDK would be to compile the app and transfer it to my Samsung mobile for testing, but this seems very cumbersome and will lead to everything taking much longer.  I've just found Apache Ripple, but didn't want to spend a day looking into it to find there's a better tool.

Is anybody able to point me at a tutorial page that gives the easiest method for testing a Cordova app with plugin support, please?  I tend to work from about 4 different computers, so something web-based that means I can pull the latest version of my code from Google Drive and start working with no setup hassle would be excellent, if it exists.

Cheers

Andy

Answer (score 0):

The Ripple Emulator has similar coverage as the Cordova Simulator. Unlike Ripple, the Simulator can be extended to support specific plugins, but it will require writing simulation code to make that happen. See the [cordova-simulate project](https://github.com/Microsoft/cordova-simulate#adding-simulation-support-to-plugins) for details on how to do that.

Otherwise, the next best option (and the most accurate) is to build the app and use remote Chrome DevTools to debug the app ([see this XDK doc page](https://software.intel.com/en-us/xdk/docs/using-remote-chrome-devtools-to-debug-android-cordova-apps) for some help with setting that up). It is not necessary to rebuild your app to make this work. If you structure your code so that you can redefine key functions using the JavaScript console, you can actually debug quite a bit without performing a rebuild and reinstall.

Use the interactive JavaScript console to redefine functions within your app and then run those redefined functions directly from the console or restart your app, in situ, using the `window.location.reload()` function. An example of using this technique can be seen [in this video](https://software.intel.com/en-us/videos/using-the-test-tab), starting at about 18:30. The video is demonstrating the use of the weinre debugger, but the debugging technique can also be applied to remote CDT when debugging a built app.